# iOS status bar with Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin

I am writing a Xamarin cross platform forms app.

Here is my main page XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="XXX.YYYY">

<TabbedPage.Children>

    <ContentPage Title="Page1" >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <SearchBar Placeholder="" Text="">
            </SearchBar>

            <ListView x:Name="listView1"  />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    ...
```

And here is the result in iOS simulator:

[image]

As you can see, i have a problem with status bar on the top of the screen.

I have solved the problem by adding 20px padding on the top, but i think this solution is ugly (let's imagine Apple wants to grow this status bar to 30px in future iOS release...)

Is there a way to say to xamarin to "pack" content bellow the status bar ?

I have also tried to hide status bar (with checkbox in plist file in iOS project) but it does not work...

Thanks

Comment: The status bar has been 20px since the beginning..... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, you will have to apply a padding to the top or set a `NavigationPage` to `App.Current.MainPage`. This will take care of the padding.

Comment: I have add Padding="0,20,0,0" in first TabbedPage but it does not work...

Comment: When Padding has no effect, use Margin. In this case, add a Margin to the ContentPage.